# Deserialize with Json.Net fails on some fields

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I try to deserialze Json into a c# object using Json.Net.

c# class:

```
public class Evaluation
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "avg")]
    public string Average { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "median")]
    public string Median { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "teacherID")]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "evalType")]
    public int EvaluationType { get; set; }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
[Test]
[TestCase()]
public void TestParsing()
{
    string json = "{" +
                "\"id\": 439476," +
                "\"avg\": \"69\"," +
                "\"median\": \"75\"," +
                "\"teacherID\": 1," +
                "\"evalType\": 1" +
                "}";

    Evaluation evaluation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Evaluation>(json);

    Assert.IsTrue(evaluation.Average.Equals("69"));
    Assert.IsTrue(evaluation.EvaluationType == 1);
}
```

This fails because evaluation.Average is null and evaluation.EvaluationType is 0. The other fields are parsed correctly.

Why is this failing?

Comment: This is a very well formed and clear question. Kudos on that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the [`DataContract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute on your class declaration should fix the problem:

```
[DataContract]
public class Evaluation
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "avg")]
    public string Average { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "median")]
    public string Median { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "teacherID")]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "evalType")]
    public int EvaluationType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the docs suggest you *should* be able to use DataMember: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm

Comment: @JonSkeet I've replicated the example locally and it seems to discard `DataMember` completely.

Comment: @JonSkeet It was missing `DataContract` attribute at the class level.

Comment: In your second example, you're still using `JsonProperty` - I suspect you meant to use `DataMember` (which I've validated *does* work when you'ev got the `DataContract`)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes i refactored the entire answer. Fixed.